# How to redirect users to the page they were previously on after a successful signin flow in NextAuth?

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a *Next.js* app with *NextAuth*.

I have a product page that contains an Add to Cart button.
If the user isn't logged in and clicks on Add to Cart, I want to redirect him to the login page.
After successful login, the user will be redirected back to the product page.

Inside the Add to Cart handler.
I used the *signIn* method which comes with NextAuth Client API.
Based on the documentation, the *signIn* method ensures that the user ends back on the page they started on after completing a sign-in flow. Note that the component which contains the Add to Cart button is a client component and I'm using the useSession hook from NextAuth to know the user login status.

```
const addProductToCart = async () => {
  if (!session) {
   await signIn()
   return
  }
 //the rest of the function's code in case the user was signed in
```

When I'm logged out and try to click on Add to Cart, I'm redirected to the login page
with the following URL on top ***localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fheadphones%2Fheadphone-beats*** so far so good.
But after a successful login, I'm getting redirected to the home page which is unexpected.

My auth options:

```
export const authOptions = {
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: 'Sign in',
        credentials: {},
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            const { email, password } = credentials

            try {
                await connectDB()
                const customer = await Customer.findOne({ email })
                if (!customer) null

                //check whether the passwords are correct
                const pwdComparisonResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, customer.password)
                if (pwdComparisonResult) {
                    return customer
                }

                return null

            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error ', error);
            }
        }
    }),
],
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
        user && (token.user = user)
        return Promise.resolve(token)
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        session.user.name = token.user.name
        session.user.email = token.user.email
        session.user.id = token.user._id
        session.user.cart = token.user.cart
        return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
},
session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
},
pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
}}
```

How do I redirect the user back to product page?
What if the user signed up before logging in how do I deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to [specify a `callbackUrl`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) to `signIn`, e.g.

```js
const addProductToCart = async () => {
  if (!session) {
   await signIn(undefined, { callbackUrl: '/products/foo' })
   return
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: Yes, I'm getting redirected to home page.